# Sqlite ExecuteNonQuery() doesn't return

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am trying to insert a record into my sqlite database as follows:

```
public void Generate()
{
    string query = $"insert into posts values('hello world', 'this is a post', 4);";

    using (var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=app.db;Version=3;"))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, dbConnection))
        {
            int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Doesn't return
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above method, control doesn't return from `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and hangs infinitely. The data is not getting inserted in the database.

I can connect to the database and read values using the `Reader`, so my connection is working. I can execute the insert query manually using the DB Browser for sqlite, so I know the query is correct.

This is the database schema for `posts`:

```
CREATE TABLE "posts" (
    "title" TEXT,
    "content" TEXT,
    "id" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

Comment: What is the schema of the table _Posts_?

Comment: CREATE TABLE "posts" (
 "title" TEXT,
 "content" TEXT,
 "id" INTEGER,
 PRIMARY KEY("id")
)

Comment: Well, the data is not getting inserted in the database. I tried debugging, but the control doesn't move past the `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: Does result = 1?  If so, query worked.  Use the debugger.

Comment: Tried your code with the same table. I am unable to reproduce any problem. The database table Posts contains the record inserted.

Comment: @LarsTech I did, but ExecuteNonQuery doesn't return anything. The control just hangs indefinitely.

Comment: @Steve, the `app.db` is located in the `App_Data` directory of an MVC application. I wonder if my code doesn't have write access to the db.

Comment: Usually App_Data is absolutely writable from the web application. Just check if the folder has permission for the IUSR user or whatever user IIS use to start the application pool

Comment: What about from a console application? The app.db is in the App_Data, but I am trying to write to it from a different console application. Will that work?

Comment: However, you have not specified the App_Data part in the connection string above

Comment: I changed the original path to keep my question simple. My real code points to the correct path.

Comment: Hmm, I copied the `app.db` in the same console project and it works. Looks like it's a permissions issue.

Comment: If you don't specify the path, the SQLite engine will create the database for you if there is no app.db in the current folder. Of course the following insert will fail because there is no table _Posts_ in the just created database. But you should see an exception

Comment: I moved the `app.db` file outside the `App_Data` and it worked.

Comment: Because you have not set the path? Did you use Server.MapPath to map the virtual directory App_Data to its physical path?

Comment: I couldn't use Server.MapPath as I was trying to access it from outside the mvc application.